# How to change toolbar button order in eclipse 4.2?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

With the old version, we just needed to drag and drop to change the positions toolbar's button. But with juno, how do we do this?

Comment: That'll be fixed in 4.2.1 (at least partially) by https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=340695

Comment: No. That is a different bug. The question is about changing the relative position of the perspective buttons with respect to each other not the ability to drag the toolbar. This still appears to be broken in Kepler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe you can re-order them in Eclipse 4.2.

However, you can choose to hide them:
  - Window -> Customize Perspective -> Tool Bar Visibility

Comment: No worries.  Mark the solution as solved if it's done though :) (+1)

Comment: While, true this does not answer the actual question. I want to reorder the buttons, not hide them. Surely there must be some sort of work around to reorder the buttons manually? Presumably the order is saved persistently in some workspace file?

Answer (score 1):

This is [bug 364046](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=364046), and has supposedly been fixed but is not yet released.

In the meantime, you can reorder the perspective buttons using the Live Application Model View. I am not sure what you need to install to get this view -- Eclipse e4 Tools perhaps?
I didn't see the view in the Show View dialog but it shows up with Ctrl-3.

Once you get the live application model view up, you need to find the Perspectives Stack,
which I found under Windows->Trimmed Window->Controls->PartSashContainer->Perspectives Stack.
Then you can reorder either by dragging/dropping in the tree view, or by the up/down buttons in the editor. I had to restart Eclipse to see the changes.

Comment: Bug 364046 was apparently fixed in Eclipse version I20140528-2000, back in 2014. In Eclipse RCP 4.7.1.v20170906-1700 _Oxygen_, it is possible to drag and drop entries in the Perspective Switcher.

Answer (score 1):

until the bug is fixed, i've found that one can:

1. figure out the order of the perspective items you are interested in
2. close all perspectives (or at least all that are in the wrong order
3. re-open in the order preferred.

if switching the last 2, just close the 2nd to last one, then re-open it, and it will be the last one.

if you want to move the first one to the last position, close it, then re-open.

if you want to move the last one to the first position, well ... you'll have to close all the others, then re-open them in the order you want.

this might involve less work than pulling in the "live application model view".  at the very least, it just worked for me after coming to this question in hopes of seeing a real answer to the problem.